# How to iterate over multiple subnets in Route Table Associations with AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a list of subnets that I would want to iterate into my public and private route table. Here is an example of my function for my public RT:

```
// This will grab the public RT and associate all public subnets to the RT.
props.pubSubnetId.forEach((public_subnets) => {
  const publicRTAssoc = new ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(this, "publicRTAssoc", {
    routeTableId: props.pubRouteTableId,
    subnetId: public_subnets
  });
});
```

I see nothing wrong with my code but when I run `cdk synth`, I get this error:

`Error: There is already a Construct with name 'publicRTAssoc' in CloudformationArchStack [CloudformationArchStack]`

I believe the iteration is interfering with the `id` in my function. Would appreciate any help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicions were correct.  You just need to give each route table association construct a unique id:

```js
// This will grab the public RT and associate all public subnets to the RT.
props.pubSubnetId.forEach((public_subnets) => {
  const publicRTAssoc = new ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(this, `publicRTAssoc_${public_subnets}`, {
    routeTableId: props.pubRouteTableId,
    subnetId: public_subnets
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed the usage of `publicRTAssoc_${public_subnets}`. Really appreciate the help!